# Multiple Font Style Combinations in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, fonts

If I want to create a font with multiple style combinations, like bold AND underline, I have to place the 'or' statement between it, like in the example below:

```
  lblArt.Font = New Font("Tahoma", 18, FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Underline)
```

If you place bold 'and' underline, it won't work, and you only get 1 of the 2 (like how the or statement should be working), while that would be the logically way to do it.  What is the reason behind this?

Comment: It is not the logical `Or` being used.  See [Logical and Bitwise Operators in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boolean logic works a bit differently than the way we use the terms in English. What's happening here is that the enumerated `FontStyle` values are actually *bit flags*, and in order to manipulate bit flags, you use [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

To *combine* two bit flags, you OR them together. An OR operation combines the two values. So imagine that `FontStyle.Bold` was 2 and `FontStyle.Underline` was 4. When you OR them together, you get 6—you've combined them together. In Boolean logic, you can think of an OR operation as returning "true" (*i.e.*, setting that bit in the result) if *either* of the bits in the two operands are set, and "false" if *neither* of the bits in the two operands are set.

You can write a truth table for such an operation as follows:

```
| A | B | A OR B |
|---|---|--------|
| 0 | 0 |   0    |
| 0 | 1 |   1    |
| 1 | 0 |   1    |
| 1 | 1 |   1    |
```

Notice that the results more closely mirror what we, in informal English, would call "and". If either one has it set, then the result has it set, too.

In contrast to OR, a bitwise AND operation only returns "true" (*i.e.*, sets that bit in the result) if *both* of the bits in the two operands are set. Otherwise, the result is "false". Again, a truth table can be written:

```
| A | B | A AND B |
|---|---|---------|
| 0 | 0 |    0    |
| 0 | 1 |    0    |
| 1 | 0 |    0    |
| 1 | 1 |    1    |
```

Assuming again that `FontStyle.Bold` has the value 2 and `FontStyle.Underline` has the value 4, if you AND them together, you get 0. This is because the values effectively cancel each other out. The net result is that you don't get any font styles—precisely why it doesn't work when you write `FontStyle.Bold And FontStyle.Underline`.

In VB, a bitwise OR operation is performed using the `Or` operator. The `And` operator performs a bitwise AND operation. So in order to do a bitwise inclusion of values, which is how you combine bit flags, you use the `Or` operator.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
lblArt.Font = New Drawing.Font("Tahoma", _
                               18,  _
                               FontStyle.Bold or FontStyle.Italic)
```

use "New Drawing.Font" instead of Font alone
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350993/vb-net-how-to-compose-and-apply-a-font-to-a-label-in-runtime)