# Applying more than one font style to a label - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, fonts, label, font-style

I have a program that will apply bold, italic, and underline, each with a button click, to a label. But I can't have 2 `fontstyles`, like a word that is bold and italic at the same time. The following code I tried will override the previous applied style with the new one.

```
Dim con4 As Label
For Each con4 In Me.Controls
   If con4.Font.Bold = False Then
        con4.Font = New Font(con4.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
   Else
        con4.Font = New Font(con4.Font, FontStyle.Regular)
   End If
```

What I want to do, is change the label to bold when the button is clicked and the label is normal, and revert it to normal if it was already bold.

I used the same code for italic and underline, but instead I used `con5` and `con6`

I soon saw that this does not allow me to make the Label Bold and Italic, for example. Each button click overrides the previous one. So if you please tell me exactly what to do.

---

Thanks guys.

Comment: I think this question will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224826/multiple-font-style-combinations-in-vb-net

Comment: @muffi - Sorry but is not too clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FontStyle` enumeration has the `Flags` attribute applied, which means that you can combine values with an `Or` operator.  For instance, to apply both Bold and Italic you use this:

```
FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic
```

The code you have is actually toggling a single style and the most correct way to do that is like this:

```
myFont = New Font(myFont, myFont.Style Xor FontStyle.Bold)
```

That will apply `Bold` if it's not and remove it if it is without affecting any other styles, so you could have two separate buttons or menu items that each toggled one style.

If you want to be able to optionally apply more than one style, e.g. using `CheckBoxes` then I'd suggest something like this:

```
Dim style = FontStyle.Regular

If useBold Then
    style = style Or FontStyle.Bold
End If

If useItalic Then
    style = style Or FontStyle.Italic
End If

myFont = New Font(myFont, style)
```

EDIT:

Here's a more complete example I just put together that uses `Buttons` to toggle styles:

```
Private Sub boldButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles boldButton.Click
    ToggleStyle(FontStyle.Bold)
End Sub

Private Sub italicButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles italicButton.Click
    ToggleStyle(FontStyle.Italic)
End Sub

Private Sub underlineButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles underlineButton.Click
    ToggleStyle(FontStyle.Underline)
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleStyle(style As FontStyle)
    Me.Label1.Font = New Font(Me.Label1.Font, Me.Label1.Font.Style Xor style)
End Sub
```

Here's a similar example that uses `CheckBoxes` to select styles:

```
Private Sub boldCheckBox_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles boldCheckBox.CheckedChanged
    SetStyle()
End Sub

Private Sub italicCheckBox_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles italicCheckBox.CheckedChanged
    SetStyle()
End Sub

Private Sub underlineCheckBox_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles underlineCheckBox.CheckedChanged
    SetStyle()
End Sub

Private Sub SetStyle()
    Dim style = FontStyle.Regular

    If Me.boldCheckBox.Checked Then
        style = style Or FontStyle.Bold
    End If

    If Me.italicCheckBox.Checked Then
        style = style Or FontStyle.Italic
    End If

    If Me.underlineCheckBox.Checked Then
        style = style Or FontStyle.Underline
    End If

    Me.Label1.Font = New Font(Me.Label1.Font, style)
End Sub
```

Comment: That is more than enough thnx